# How to show that $F(x)$ continuous?

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

$F:\Big(C[0,1],||.||_2\Big)\rightarrow \Big(C[0,1],||.||_3\Big)$

$x\rightarrow F(x)(t)=\int^t_0x(s)ds,\quad\quad0 \le t\le 1 $

Show that F is continuous.

F is linear. for n=0,1,2.. $x_n(t)=t^n,0 \le t\le 1  $

I found $||F(x_n)||_3 =\frac{1}{(n+1)^3\sqrt[3]{3n+4}}$

and $||x_n||_2=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

so $sup\frac{||F(x_n||_3}{||x_n||_2}=0$ when $n\to \infty$

May I say it is continuous because it is linear and $sup\frac{||F(x_n||_3}{||x_n||_2}\le +\infty$ ?

Comment: Something I do not get: here $x$ is a function, so is $F(x)$. Do you mean $F(x)$ is always the constant function $\int_0^1 x ds$? Moreover should add some words on the fact that it is enough to check $\frac{\|F(x)\|}{\|x\|}$ on the functions $x_n$...

Comment: @Milly my bad it is $\int^t_0x(s)ds$